# ToolStripSplitButton Show Dropdown

Tags: .net, winforms, button

I have a VB NET form with one ToolStripSplitButton on it.  The visible property is set by default to False.  When I process the user request on the main part of the form, I may encounter soft errors that I don't want to use a msgbox for.  What I do is add these soft errors into the DropDownItems of the control and make the control visible.  If the user wants to see the messages, they can click on the menu icon which displays the DropDownItems.

I'd like to make this more sophisticated. I'm looking for suggestions/best practices.  What can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this code to allow users to see the messages merely by hovering over the control.

```
Private Sub sbtnToolStrip_MouseHover(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles sbtnToolStrip.MouseHover
        sbtnToolStrip.ShowDropDown()
End Sub

Private Sub sbtnToolStrip_MouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles sbtnToolStrip.MouseLeave
        sbtnToolStrip.HideDropDown()
End Sub
```

And there is no need to code the click event!

Comment: How can i check if DropDown is shown to user. i have to check if dropdown is shown  ??

Comment: @ErMayank The user should see the control if the visible property is set to true.  The control has an arrow on the right to enable them to see the dropdown.  They would have to click on it.  However, with the code above, all they have to do it hover over the control.  In the MouseHover method, you can do whatever you like to satisfy your need to tell whether the user saw the dropdown.